# VECM coefficients and equations

Tags: cointegration, vector-error-correction-model, macroeconomics

I am building a macroeconomic model using VECM. I have a dataset divided into training and testing set and I am forecasting the future values of **y**. I performed all the testing and I want to get the coefficients of the combination to be able to calculate the same or similar in excel.

I am predicting now values for 2021 using values from 2014-2020, but I need to be able to update the predicted values for example in August 2021 using already the real values from previous months without running the R code again.

Is it at all possible to get the coefficients for the independent variables combination?

Here are my first 20 predicted values:

[image]

And here the Johansen procedure:

[image]

Model summary:
[image]

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: Not sure I get what your problem is. Do you want to reestimate the model coefficients with an expanded sample without R? Or do you want to calculate one-step-ahead forecasts using the original coefficients when some new data points are added? Or something else?

Comment: Hi Richard, I want to calculate the one-step-ahead forecasts using the original coefficients when some new data points are updated. But it should be performed out of R.